# How to not loose the selected item index in a post back using ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, postback, web-parts

I am writing a visual web part which has ajax implemented. 
I have bunch of web controls like checkboxlist,dropdownlist,radiobuttonlist.
I have set autopostback equals to true so that some server events happens in every item selection.

I want to retain the cursor in each control after selection right now i have focus on the control but the selection index goes to the 0 item. 
Is there a way to retain it in the same item after postback. so that nobody feels that there is even a postback.

here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="subj" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>                                   
    <asp:RadioButtonList   ID="subj" runat="server"  
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rsubj_SelectedIndexChanged"
            AutoPostBack="True"         
            ValidationGroup="UserProfile">                                
        <asp:ListItem Value="mans">Humans</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="rman primates">Non-Human primates</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="bidents">Rodents</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="teachers">Others</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and server side on the indexchanged event i am setting the focus like this

```
protected void rsubj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rdb_studysubj.Focus();
```

is there a way we can preserve the selected item index evertime the page postbacks in the current control. I have different controls like radiobuttonlist, checkboxlist,dropdownlist. i dont want to loose the selected item index after postback...
any help

Comment: Is there any other code updating the selection? I've never had this problem myself and from what I can see of your code there are a few peculiarities: e.g. `OnSelectedIndexChange` does not call the written method `rsubj_SelectedIndexChanged` I'm guessing that rdb_studysubj is a different control again

Comment: can you post your pageload method

Comment: my pageload method have nothing for now.i have something like 20-25 web controls like that. i am trying to figure out if i have to write something in a postback or asynchronous ajax can help fixing it

Comment: the functions names are correct it is just mistyped here